# Delete overlapping faces between two objects

Tags: objects

Is it possible to select parts of one layer in the outliner and then delete it from another layer in the outliner?

I have two objects that overlap and I want to delete the parts that overlap.

I want to be able to select the top and delete the vertices from the body in the shape of the top so that the object underneath the top is deleted but the top remains.
I know how to do it face by face but I was hoping there was a shortcut like the selection tool in Photoshop that works between layers.

[image: Top]

[image: Body]

[image: Outliner]

Comment: Use the 'edit' link below your post and add some screenshots, that way people can see your situation and give you an answer much more effectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the mask modifier. If you want another work around select in the mesh the limits that you want to cut and hit the V key to separate after that hit the L key to select the mesh island then delete the unwanted piece. You may also separate the selection as an object with the p key.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way from separate objects, but if they are the same object you can try clean up operations such as mesh > vertices > remove doubles or a [dissolve operation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/deleting.html).

I've tried doing this cleanly before, for example with an import from zbrush and I find I can rarely get it to work the way I want. I've always had to go back to planning the objects of my model ahead of time.